# Make button inactive only when clicked on other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

I've the following situation:

I have a "next" step button:

```
<a href="/NL/checkout/selectshippingaddress?addressId=" class="customNextStep">
    <input type="button" class="button-1 shipping-adress-next-step-button" value="Next" name="nextstep">
</a>
```

This buttons should be inactive in first place. It should only be clickable when a user clicks on a other button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="" class="button-1 select-shipping-address-button" data-itemid="197" value="Send to this address">
```

I hope someone can help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) of jQuery

```
$("input[name='nextstep']").attr('disabled','disabled');
$('.button-1').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("input[name='nextstep']").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

[**Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/YhxcH/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disabled` attribute to switch on and off a button.

```
//on document.ready, disable your second button
$(selector).prop("disabled", true);

// on the click on first button enable it again
$(selector_first_button).click(function() {
    $(selector).prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following in your code:

```
    <input type="button" id="bt1" value="button 1" />
    <input type="button" id="bt2" value="button 2" disabled="disabled" />
```

now apply any logic you want, like

```
$(function(){
    $("#bt1").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#bt2").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `disabled` attribute of button. Like,

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('next_button').disabled=false;" class="button-1 select-shipping-address-button" data-itemid="197" value="Send to this address">
<input type="button" class="button-1 shipping-adress-next-step-button" value="Next" name="nextstep" disabled='true' id='next_button'>
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7VmNX/)

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
jQuery('input[name=nextstep]').attr('disabled','disabled')
$('.select-shipping-address-button').on('click',function(e){
    jQuery('input[name=nextstep]').removeAttr('disabled')
})
```

Here is the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uDayA/)